# Logitech Optical Mouse Frozen In Middle of Windows XP Pro Screen

Tags: windows-xp, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech Optical Mouse/Keyboard. I have been using them just fine with the system drivers for almost a year now. I recently updated my Kaspersky software and rebooted. Now the mouse is frozen in the middle of my screen.

I am not able to login to the Windows XP Pro box that has the frozen mouse (because I can't work the mouse) but am able to remote desktop to this computer.

Things I know / have tried:

- When I boot on the problem computer, I am able to use the keyboard, but not the mouse.
- I have installed the latest version of Logitech's SetPoint (with the updated drivers) on the problem computer (via remote desktop) and that didn't seem to matter.
- I bought new batteries for the mouse and that didn't matter.
- I have tried the mouse/keyboard on another computer and the mouse works just fine there.

My suspicion is that the Kaspersky install has overwritten a driver of some sort.

Things I have not done (and would appreciate detailed steps if you feel this is the way to go):

1) Uninstalled all the mouse drivers on the machine and reboot. Then, reinstall.

Note: When I get to the Device Manager I don't see an option for Human Interface Devices (where the mouse device is). Here are my options:

- Computer
- Disk Drives
- DVD/CD-Rom drives
- Floppy controllers
- IDE ATA/ATAPI
- Imaging devices
- Network Adapters
- Other devices
- Ports
- Processors
- Sound video and gaming
- System devices
- USB controllers

Also, I should point out that **Video Controller** is the only thing under **Other devices** and it has a yellow exclamation mark. The same is true for all the items under **Universal Serial Bus controllers**. I think this means I have to update my BIOS but, since my mouse was working just fine without doing that, I don't think that is my problem. So, how do I get to my **Mouse Device**?

2) Update my BIOS.

Note: As pointed out above, I don't think this matters as my mouse was working just fine under my computer's current BIOS version.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried booting in safe mode? If Kaspersky has overwritten some driver, they should have been updated with the driver installation procedure. Is Kaspersky blocking the drivers somehow? If yes -> search the appropriate rule

Comment: Thanks - that was a good idea but I don't see any rules blocking my mouse drivers. I had Kaspersky running prior to the problem and it doesn't seem like the updated version has done anything different to my rules settings.

Comment: Try to disconnect that computer from Internet and uninstall Kaspersky. If it won't fix the problem, then it's not Kaspersky. If it will, then you have a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the driver.  Press Windows-R to bring up the **Run** dialog, type **compmgmt.msc** and press **Enter**.  Navigate to the **Device Manager**.  Locate the mouse device (it's usually under the **Human Interface Devices** branch).  Right-click the mouse device and select **Uninstall**.  You will most likely be prompted to restart.  Either way, restart your computer.  Windows XP should re-detect the mouse and install the appropriate driver.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For my response, please see item number one at the bottom of my post entitled: Uninstalled all the mouse drivers on the machine and reboot. Then, reinstall.

Comment: If all your USB devices are showing problems in the Device Manager, you should re-install the drivers for your motherboard (available on their web site).  Once you do that, Windows should re-detect your mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected any other device to the USB port that your mouse is connected to (via USB hub). Try disconnecting all USB devices except for mouse and keyboard. It could be another USB device that is failing. Also try a different USB port.

Kaspersky has the option to disable protection. Does the mouse start working if you disable protection. You can always re-enable protection once you are done testing.